# Swift: decoding an array of mixed values

Tags: swift

I have a `Decodable` struct in Swift, with an array that might contain ints or a string representation of a double:

```
{
    "result": {
        "XXBTZUSD": [
            [
                1616662740,
                "52591.9",
                "52599.9",
                "52591.8",
                "52599.9",
                "52599.1",
                "0.11091626",
                5
            ]
        ],
        "last": 1616662920
    }
}
```

My struct looks like this:

```
struct OHLCData: Decodable {
    var pair: [[Double]]
    var last: Int
    
    private struct CodingKeys: CodingKey {
        var intValue: Int?
        var stringValue: String
        init?(stringValue: String) {  self.stringValue = stringValue  }
        init?(intValue: Int) {
            self.stringValue = String(intValue)
            self.intValue = intValue
        }
        static let last = CodingKeys(stringValue: "last")!
        static func makeKey(name: String) -> CodingKeys {
            return CodingKeys(stringValue: name)!
        }
    }
    
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        last = try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .last)
        let key = container.allKeys.first(where: { $0.stringValue != "last" } )?.stringValue
        pair = try container.decode([[Double]].self, forKey: .makeKey(name: key!))
    }
    
}
```

It falls over at run time because the double type in `[[Double]]` doesn't correspond to what might be an int in the array.

I tried to create a `typealias` but I get:

```
// Non-protocol, non-class type 'String' cannot be used within a protocol-constrained type
// Non-protocol, non-class type 'Double' cannot be used within a protocol-constrained type
typealias PairType = String & Double
```

How can I work around this?

Comment: Maybe better to decode the inner array to a custom struct, to me it looks like each element has a specific meaning

Comment: I have no control over the JSON. It’s coming from a third party API

Comment: @serlingpa `Any` does NOT conform to `Codable`. Better to use `JSONSerialization`.

Comment: I’d like to avoid that if I can. Is there no way to specify a type for both int and double that can be decoded? Like extend the two with a protocol conformance?

Comment: I didn't say you should change the json, my comment referred to the current json

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could decode it using something like:

```
enum Either<A, B> {
    case left(A)
    case right(B)
}

extension Either: Codable where A: Codable, B: Codable {
    struct NeitherError: Error {}

    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        switch self {
        case let .left(a):
            try a.encode(to: encoder)
        case let .right(b):
            try b.encode(to: encoder)
        }
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
        if let a = try? container.decode(A.self) {
            self = .left(a)
        }
        else if let b = try? container.decode(B.self) {
            self = .right(b)
        }
        else {
            throw NeitherError()
        }
    }
}

let input = """
[
               1616662740,
               "52591.9",
               "52599.9",
               "52591.8",
               "52599.9",
               "52599.1",
               "0.11091626",
               5
           ]
"""

let data = input.data(using: .utf8)!
let things = try! JSONDecoder().decode([Either<Int, String>].self, from: data)
```

You might want to split the Codable constraint into two extensions for Encodable and Decodable, and you might want to make a custom type which is `StringifiedDouble` which only decodes if the thing is a String AND is a stringified representation of a Double, e.g.

```
struct StringifiedDouble: Codable {
    var value: Double
    struct TypeError: Error {}

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
        let str = try container.decode(String.self)

        guard let value = Double(str) else {
            throw TypeError()
        }

        self.value = value
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome. I was thinking something along those lines. I’m out and about at the moment but I’ll try it when I get home 

Comment: @serlingpa Do you really think it is worth all this just to get rid of Root? I would keep it as you had before.

Comment: Get rid of root? What do you mean @LeoDabus? The code falls over at runtime.

Comment: I mean no need to create a custom decoder. Just use the root structure to decode users